# New lines after \ in lstlisting

Tags: line-breaking, lstlisting

I have very simple bash listing

```
\begin{lstlisting}
$ docker create --name my-nginx \
  --network host \
  --publish 8080:80 \
  nginx:latest
\end{lstlisting}
```

It looks fine in PDF, but once I try to copy it to the clipboard from the PDF it doesn't have any line breaks after backslashes and looks like this:

```
docker create --name my-nginx \--network host \ --publish 8080:80 \ nginx:latest
```

Full MWE

```
\documentclass[handout,mathserif,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings} %code listing
\usepackage{hyperref} %mailto link
\usepackage{graphicx} %table text resize
\usepackage{booktabs} %table rullers
\usepackage{makecell} %cells newline

% Стиль презентации
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\lstset{
   basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
\begin{document}

\section{Host драйвер}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Host драйвер}
   \begin{lstlisting}
$ docker create --name my-nginx \
 --network host \
 --publish 8080:80 \
 nginx:latest
   \end{lstlisting}
   \begin{block}{--network host}
   позволяет контейнеру получить доступ к сетевым интерфейсам хост системы
   \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I played around with a few example documents and the result is the same. Sumatra, Adobe Reader and Google Chrome generally copy all line breaks in the PDF. Edge and Firefox ignore all line breaks and copy the text as one long line. I guess an argument could be made for both. I'm not sure if the PDF standard has something to say on the matter or if the viewers a free to do whatever they want (I strongly suspect the latter).

Comment: sorry. Thanks for testing, looks like it's not needed to be edited since it didn't add any info. That could be a problem with Mac viewer. I'll try to check on win. Thanks for test. Here is a presentation itself http://docker-meetups.osfonder.ru/Март%202019/Работа%20с%20сетями.pdf

Comment: copy & pasting of code from a pdf is not reliable. You should embed or attach the code (with embedfile or attachfile2 package) if you want to provide an exact copy of the code.